# Flutter web google sign in - the popup doesn't show, sign in button does nothing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

I have a Flutter web app which uses Google sign in, managed with Firebase. If I run it with `flutter run -d chrome`, when I click on the sign in button, it pops up the Google sign in pane, however after writing in my email address, it says that it's an unsafe browser and that I should try to use another browser. After some research, I founda workaround, opening the `localhost:5000` from a separate chrome window. In this case, the issue is that it doesn't show the popup.

I don't know if it has to do anything with the issue, but when I inspect the element it shows this warning:
[image]
[image]

The code I use to handle the sign-in:

```
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart";

class GoogleSignInService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;
  GoogleSignInService(this._googleSignIn, this._auth);

  Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async {
    FirebaseUser user;
    bool isSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    if (isSignedIn) {
      user = await _auth.currentUser();
    } else {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
      user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

I call the handlesignin in the onPressed of my sign in button. I use version 4.5.4 of the google_sign_in package. I have done everything suggested here: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web

Comment: did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: No, I still haven't.